# How to convert DateTime into long miliseconds android in the given below format?

Tags: java

`2018-07-12T00:00:00.000+05:30` into miliseconds? Let me know how to convert it

```
@Override
public void onDateSelected(@NonNull final DateTime dateSelected) {
    // log it for demogetdata();

    Log.i("HorizontalPicker", "Selected date is " + dateSelected.toString());
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss z");
    try {
        Date mDate = sdf.parse(dateSelected.toString());
        long timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
        System.out.println("Date in milli :: " + timeInMilliseconds);
        getdata(timeInMilliseconds);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: You seems to did it, what is the problem ?

Comment: Simpledateformat pattern was not right. Correct pattern was "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"